# Submit Button Not Processing PHP form

Tags: php, html, forms, email, webforms

http://www.bridgetjoy.com/Web/requestInfo.html

I am having trouble getting the above form to process...here is my php processing code, I am getting it to redirect to my success page but it is not showing up in my inbox. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
   $to = "bridgetjoymedia@gmail.com" ;     //put your email address on which you want to receive the information
   $subject = "Information Request";   //set the subject of email.
   $headers = "From: $email";
   $message = "<table><tr><td>Title :</td><td>".$_POST['title']."</td></tr>
               <tr><td>First Name :</td><td>".$_POST['firstName']."</td></tr>
               <tr><td>Last Name :</td><td>".$_POST['lastName']."</td></tr>
               <tr><td>Degree :</td><td>".$_POST['degree']."</td></tr>
               <tr><td>Address :</td><td>".$_POST['address1']."</td></tr>
               <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>".$_POST['address2']."</td></tr>
               <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>".$_POST['address3']."</td></tr>
               <tr><td>City :</td><td>".$_POST['city']."</td></tr>
               <tr><td>State :</td><td>".$_POST['state']."</td></tr>
               <tr><td>ZipCode :</td><td>".$_POST['zipCode']."</td></tr>
               <tr><td>Country :</td><td>".$_POST['country']."</td></tr>
               <tr><td>E-mail Address :</td><td>".$_POST['email']."</td></tr>
               <tr><td> Secondary E-mail Address :</td><td>".$_POST['email2']."</td></tr>
               <tr><td>Primary Phone :</td><td>".$_POST['phone1']."</td></tr>
               <tr><td>Primary Phone Location :</td><td>".$_POST['phone1_location']."</td></tr>
               <tr><td>Secondary Phone :</td><td>".$_POST['phone2']."</td></tr>
               <tr><td>Secondary Phone Location :</td><td>".$_POST['phone2_location']."</td></tr>
               <tr><td>Fax :</td><td>".$_POST['phone3']."</td></tr>
               <tr><td>Reason for Request :</td><td>".$_POST['relation']."</td></tr>
               <tr><td>Reason for Request :</td><td>".$_POST['relation_specify']."</td>
               <tr><td>Reason for Request :</td><td>".$_POST['physician_specialty']."</td>
               <tr><td>Reason for Request :</td><td>".$_POST['surgeon_specialty']."</td>
               <tr><td>Reason for Request :</td><td>".$_POST['prof_specify']."</td></tr>
               <tr><td>Reason for Request :</td><td>".$_POST['other_specify']."</td></tr>
               <tr><td>Diagnosis :</td><td>".$_POST['diagnosis']."</td></tr>
               <tr><td>Insurance :</td><td>".$_POST['insurance']."</td></tr>
               <tr><td>How did you hear of Avery Biomedical :</td><td>".$_POST['source']."</td></tr>
               <tr><td>Comments :</td><td>".$_POST['comments']."</td></tr>
               </table>" ;

    $send_contact = mail($to,$subject, $headers,$message);


// Check, if message sent to your email
// display message "We've recived your information"
if($send_contact){
header("Location: success.html");
exit();}
else {

header("Location: failure.html");
exit();}
}
?>
```

Comment: Have you checked the mail logs? Your Gmail spam folder? Can you send to a different email address?

Comment: Not the issue, but always sanitise your input.

Comment: You may want to look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055460/how-to-sanitze-user-input-in-php-before-mailing) for tips on security.

Comment: Sometimes it scares me to find out exactly who is asking for help on Stackoverflow. This is one of those times ;)

Comment: pycoder112358 not entirely sure what you meant by this comment but it would be nice for people to only respond with relevant information as this is a place for people seeking help to come to not a place to be ridiculed for asking questions. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Emails sent by mail() function is blocked due is used by scammers try to use sendmail from PEAR or a smtp class

phpmailer https://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/

PEAR sendmail https://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail.send.php

Look at [PHP: mail() vs SendMail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1883615/php-mail-vs-sendmail)

Comment: I changed my code and got...
Fatal error: Call to undefined method PEAR_Error::send() in /home/content/b/r/i/bridgetjoy24/html/Web/process.php on line 53= $mail = $smtp->send($to, $subject, $headers, $body);

Comment: Did you verify if PEAR is installed in your PHP?

Comment: Try phpmailer, it don't need PEAR

Answer (score 0):

Many mail services, such as Gmail, vigorously check for spam, and much of the spam you would otherwise receive simply bounces, rather than even making it to your spam folder!

To prevent this, it helps if the mail server you are sending from has valid MX and SPF records, although this is fairly technical for most people. However, because Gmail is fairly well known, many services do not bounce email origination from smtp.mail.google.com (Gmail). Therefore, you might benefit from setting up an account for your script to use on Gmail, and then using a third-party library to connect to the account and send/receive emails.

If you haven't looked into it, SwiftMailer allows you to send mail on behalf of a Gmail account using PHP.